# Simple HTML & css table stupid issue, easy solution

Tags: html, css

I have this simple table newsletter design and I cannot identify what causes the table to be wider than I set it to be.

```
    <table cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" border="1" vallign="top" align="center" max-width="600" style="height:auto;" >
  <tr>
    <td background="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" max-width="600" height="440" alt="Lighouse in Germany" bgcolor="#333333" style="display:block; background-repeat: no-repeat;" valign="middle"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 440px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" color="#333333" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
      <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="30" max-width="600">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><br>
            <img alt="" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset-2.png" width="88" height="47" align="center" link="" style="display:block;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">
           <font style="font-weight:100;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff !important;">
            <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="font-weight:100;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 1em;">
            WEBSITE</anpa>
            <anpa href="##TellAFriend##" style="font-weight:none;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 1em;">
            FORWARD</anpa>
            <anpa href="http://www.anpdm.com/form/4743504075464B5943/414358407446455F4571" style="font-weight:none;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 1em;">
            SUBSCRIBE</anpa>
            <anpa href="##OptOutAll##" style="font-weight:none;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
            UNSUBSCRIBE<br>
            </anpa></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="600" align="center" valign="middle"><font style="font-weight:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff !important;">
          <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org">
          Baltic Development Forum</anpa></font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <font style="font-weight:100;font-family:Myriad Pro; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff !important;">

        LATEST BDF NEWS ESPECIALLY FOR YOU
              </font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <!-- <td  align="center" style="background-image:url(http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/buttonEmpty.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 184px 38px; background-position: center; padding: 9px;" alt="">
            <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: middle;">
            WEBSITE</anpa>
            </td>-->

            <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="height:35px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:160px;" arcsize="58%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d1003e">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.bdforum.org"
style="background-color:#d1003e;border-radius:20px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;line-height:35px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:160px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">WEBSITE</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you could help me I would really appreciate it. I am kind of a beginner. Especially with writing html for emails as its super annoying with different supports

Comment: omg... is that VML? I haven't seen that in a long time lol

Comment: could not find a better way of putting background and button into a newsletter that would open in outlook

Comment: ya I understand... that was the last time I saw it... when I used it for an email for outlook lol

Comment: You are setting `max-width` to be 600 while elements inside have width of `600px` as well and additionally you have `cellpadding` 30 which adds 30px from each side

Comment: "max-width" is not a property supported by the html `table` element. There is however a CSS property of that name, which is probably what you're looking for. You could try `style="max-width: 600px"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have to put `max-width="600"` inside the style attribute since `max-width` not a valid attribute for `table`, fix your problem like this `style="height:auto;max-width:600px"`

**UPDATE**

To handle the extra pixels on right and bottom add this `style="padding: 0;width: 100%;"` to the first `td`

Comment: thank you, now I only have a 1 or 2 px outline on right and bottom for unknown to me reason, Think you could help?

Comment: I have updated the solution for the pixels issue, if this solve your issue kindly consider my answer as the correct one :)

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for some reason did you try it?

Comment: love ya all guys. It kept me in frustration for at least an hour !

Answer (score 0):

Put max-width attribute inside **style** tag

```
<table cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" border="1" vallign="top" align="center"  style="height:auto;max-width:600px" >
```

For border issue, you can update table tag like

```
<table cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" border="1" vallign="top" align="center"  style="height:auto;max-width:600px;border-bottom: none!important;border-right: none !important;" >
```

```html
<table cellpadding="" cellspacing="0" border="1" vallign="top" align="center"  style="height:auto;max-width:600px;border-bottom: none!important;border-right: none !important;" >
  <tr>
    <td background="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" max-width="600" height="440" alt="Lighouse in Germany" bgcolor="#333333" style="display:block; background-repeat: no-repeat;" valign="middle"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="max-width: 600px; max-height: 440px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/background-100.jpg" color="#333333" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
      <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="30" max-width="600">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><br>
            <img alt="" src="http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/Asset-2.png" width="88" height="47" align="center" link="" style="display:block;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="middle">
           <font style="font-weight:100;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff !important;">
            <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="font-weight:100;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 1em;">
            WEBSITE</anpa>
            <anpa href="##TellAFriend##" style="font-weight:none;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 1em;">
            FORWARD</anpa>
            <anpa href="http://www.anpdm.com/form/4743504075464B5943/414358407446455F4571" style="font-weight:none;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding-right: 1em;">
            SUBSCRIBE</anpa>
            <anpa href="##OptOutAll##" style="font-weight:none;color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
            UNSUBSCRIBE<br>
            </anpa></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="600" align="center" valign="middle"><font style="font-weight:none;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; color: #ffffff !important;">
          <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org">
          Baltic Development Forum</anpa></font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <font style="font-weight:100;font-family:Myriad Pro; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff !important;">

        LATEST BDF NEWS ESPECIALLY FOR YOU
              </font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <!-- <td  align="center" style="background-image:url(http://img.anpdm.com/BalticDevelopmentForum/buttonEmpty.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 184px 38px; background-position: center; padding: 9px;" alt="">
            <anpa href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff; vertical-align: middle;">
            WEBSITE</anpa>
            </td>-->

            <div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.bdforum.org" style="height:35px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:160px;" arcsize="58%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#d1003e">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://www.bdforum.org"
style="background-color:#d1003e;border-radius:20px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;line-height:35px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:160px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">WEBSITE</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]--></td>
  </tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you ! Love the response at this site. You guys are amazing !

Comment: I have tried this one as well and it seems like it does not work, thanks for your good will tho !